# Non-broken (round-trip capable) ConvertFrom-Json / ConvertTo-Json in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, roundtrip

PowerShell is unable to reliably round-trip JSON by default. How can I ensure that such JSON *is* correctly round-tripped?

Here is a minimal example of the broken round-trip serialization:

```
PS> '{"a":[{"b":{}}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
{"a":[{"b":""}]}
```

The unexpected change from `{}` to `""` results in JSON which is no longer valid.

This is under version 5.1:

```
PS> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.15063.674
```

Similarly, `'[{"b":{}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json` is also questionable, as discussed in https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/15123162-convertto-json-doesn-t-serialize-simple-objects-pr. However, consider that questionable nature *not* covered in this question.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with `-Depth`. Setting a "higher depth" results in round-trip behavior working as expected. Having the depth end as 'a string', as opposed to say, `null`, is very unfortunate.

Comment: ConvertTo-Json's default depth of 2 with no warning has been talked about often.

Comment: @js2010 Vote to close as duplicate please. I wish I had found such "often talked about" discussion *much* sooner in my day..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22260605/2864740 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/32775099/2864740

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected ConvertTo-Json results? Answer: it has a default -Depth of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583677/unexpected-convertto-json-results-answer-it-has-a-default-depth-of-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of PEBKAC, a little bit of Why Is That The Behavior?!

It seems to be an issue with `-Depth` and the pruning logic. Setting a "higher depth" results in round-trip behavior working as expected. Having the truncation end as a string, as opposed to say `null`, seems unfortunate - although possibly consistent if one finds that "To String" is the correct termination.

Change to "" (unexpected):

```
PS> '{"a":[{"b":{}}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 2
'{"a":[{"b":""}]}'
```

Round-trip (expected):

```
PS> '{"a":[{"b":{}}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 3
'{"a":[{"b":{}}]}'
```